# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unsupported endpoint address: ws://

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, cxf, stomp

I'm battling this for the past 7 days and getting out of ideas. I got two WSDL files from which I'm generating the DTO's and the service & port classes. I first tried this with Micronaut but now I'm just trying to make it work with Spring.

I'm using Apache CXF for the generating of the sources. The Endpoint is using SOAP&STOMP as you can see from the ws:// URL. Am I missing something out? ANY help is appreciated! Thanks

I'm just trying to get any reasonable response from the service. Should probably be a 400 as a BAD REQUEST or maybe 401 UNAUTHORIZED. Looks like I'm not even managing to call the service.

Here is what I have:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>soap</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>soap</name>
    <description>Soap</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyWSDL1.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyWSDL2.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**myService.java**

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "myService",
        targetNamespace = "http://my.namespace.com/rest/of/the/path/v2",
        wsdlLocation = "file:/location/to/my/wsdl/MyWsdl1.wsdl")
@Service
public class MyService implements MyServicePortType {

    MyServiceName service = new MyServiceName(MyServiceName.WSDL_LOCATION, MyServiceName.SERVICE);

    @Override
    public Response searchEntity(SearchType searchType) throws FaultMessage {
        return service.getServicePort().search(searchType);
    }
//rest of the methods which I have to implement
```

**myTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test() throws FaultMessage {
        myService.search(new SearchType());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the whole time this:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unsupported endpoint address: ws://rest/of/the/url

    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory.createDefault(TransportTubeFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory.create(TransportTubeFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1105)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:988)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:846)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:432)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:61)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.searchVehicles(Unknown Source)
    at com.demo.soap.MyService.search(MyService.java:34)
    at com.demo.soap.ApplicationTests.test(ApplicationTests.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: Use a http or https endpoint!

Comment: It's not up to me. We got the WSDL files and need to make the connection.